# Spark scala how to remove the columns that are not in common between 2 dataframes

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, drop

I have 2 dataframes, the first one has 53 columns and the second one has 132 column.
I want to compare the 2 dataframes and remove all the columns that are not in common between the 2 dataframes and then display each dataframe containing only those columns that are common.

What I did so far is to get a list of all the column that dont't match, but I don't know how to drop them.

```
    val diffColumns = df2.columns.toSet.diff(df1.columns.toSet).union(df1.columns.toSet.diff(df2.columns.toSet))
```

This is getting me a scala.collection.immutable.Set[String].
Now I'd like to use this to drop these columns from each dataframe. Something like that, but this is not working...

```
    val newDF1 = df1.drop(diffColumns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.drop` function accepts a list of columns, not the `Set` object, so you need to convert it to Seq and "expand it" using, the `: _*` syntax, like, this:

```scala
df.drop(diffColumns.columns.toSet.toSeq: _*)
```

Also, instead of generating diff, it could be just easier to do intersect to find common columns, and use `.select` on each dataframe to get the same columns:

```scala
val df = spark.range(10).withColumn("b", rand())
val df2 = spark.range(10).withColumn("c", rand())
val commonCols = df.columns.toSet.intersect(df2.columns.toSet).toSeq.map(col)
df.select(commonCols: _*)
df2.select(commonCols: _*)
```